# Java Build Error when adding javax.smartcardio to project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, smartcard

I am trying to add some simple smart card reader functionality to one of our applications and I keep getting a build error that I can't figure out, so I'm looking for input or any advice I can find that will help me get the project to compile after importing javax.smartcardio in one of the new classes.

I initially created a simple class with one string parsing method and a main method. As a standalone project, I can run the class just fine without errors and all of the expected info from the card reader and card gets printed to the console via System.out as expected, so I don't think there's any issues with the code that I have brought over to my project from this early test project.

But now that I've imported smartcardio into the new class, my project won't compile. I have tried removing and re-adding the JRE System library as suggested in several other posts here, but I think this might be a different issue. When compiling, it seems like the compiler isn't recognizing or can't find rt.jar even though I have checked repeatedly and the jar is there in the JRE folder.

Here's the error, any help is highly appreciated. Let me know if more info is needed.

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (compilegwt) @ hwslqc ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] GWT compilation: hwslqc
     [java] Compiling module com.prusa.hwslqc.hwslqc
     [java]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
     [java] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.getType(BuildTypeMap.java:730)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.access$000(BuildTypeMap.java:99)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap$BuildDeclMapVisitor.visit(BuildTypeMap.java:195)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:237)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.traverse(Block.java:127)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TryStatement.traverse(TryStatement.java:853)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:239)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1239)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createPeersForNonTypeDecls(BuildTypeMap.java:637)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:514)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:523)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:599)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
     [java]       [ERROR] <no source info>: public final class javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory
     [java]     extends java.lang.Object
     [java] /*   fields   */
     [java] private static final [unresolved] java.lang.String PROP_NAME
     [java] private static final [unresolved] java.lang.String defaultType
     [java] private static final [unresolved] javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory defaultFactory
     [java] private final [unresolved] Unresolved type javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactorySpi spi
     [java] private final [unresolved] Unresolved type java.security.Provider provider
     [java] private final [unresolved] java.lang.String type
     [java] /*   methods   */
     [java] [unresolved] private void <init>(Unresolved type javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactorySpi, Unresolved type java.security.Provider, java.lang.String) 
     [java] public static javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory getDefault() 
     [java] [unresolved] public static java.lang.String getDefaultType() 
     [java] [unresolved] public static javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory getInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object) throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
     [java] [unresolved] public static javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory getInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String) throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException, Unresolved type java.security.NoSuchProviderException
     [java] [unresolved] public static javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory getInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, Unresolved type java.security.Provider) throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
     [java] [unresolved] public Unresolved type java.security.Provider getProvider() 
     [java] [unresolved] public java.lang.String getType() 
     [java] public javax.smartcardio.CardTerminals terminals() 
     [java] [unresolved] public java.lang.String toString() 
     [java] /*   members   */
     [java] Unresolved type javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory$NoneCardTerminals
     [java] Unresolved type javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory$NoneFactorySpi
     [java] Unresolved type javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory$NoneProvider
     [java] 
     [java] 
     [java] 
     [java]       [ERROR] at SwipeCardUtil.java(48): TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.721s
```

And here's the very simple classthat's causing the compilation error at line 48:

```
package com.prusa.hwslqc.client.ui.util;

import java.util.List;

import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.smartcardio.CardException;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;



/**
 * @author SWESTF01
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class SwipeCardUtil 
{

    /**
     * @param theBytes
     * @return theByteArray as a hex string
     */
    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] theBytes)          
    {             
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(theBytes.length * 2);             

        for (int i = 0; i < theBytes.length; i++) 
        {               
            int byteRead = theBytes[i] & 0xff;               
            if (byteRead < 16) 
            {                 
                sb.append('0');               
            }               
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(byteRead));          
        }             
        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();          
     }

    /**
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public static void readCard()
    {                 
        try 
        {
            // Show the list of available terminals
            TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();

            List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
            if (terminals.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("No terminals found.");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Terminal: " + terminals.get(0).getName());

            // Get the first terminal in the list
            CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
            boolean cardHasBeenRead = false;

            if(!terminal.isCardPresent())
            {
                System.out.println("Please insert a card.");
            }

            //8 hours = 28800000
            //1 day = 86400000
            while(terminal.waitForCardPresent(86400000))
            {

                if(!cardHasBeenRead)
                {
                    // Establish a connection with the card using
                    // "T=0", "T=1", "T=CL" or "*"
                    Card card = terminal.connect("*");

                    System.out.println("Card: " + card);

                    // Get ATR
                    byte[] baATR = card.getATR().getBytes();

                    System.out.println("ATR: " + SwipeCardUtil.byteArrayToHexString(baATR));

                    // Disconnect
                    // true: reset the card after disconnecting card.
                    card.disconnect(true);
                    cardHasBeenRead = true;
                }

                if(!terminal.isCardPresent())
                {
                    cardHasBeenRead = false;
                    System.out.println("Please insert a card.");
                }
             }
        } 
        catch (CardException ex) {
            System.out.println("Please connect a Card Reader and restart the program.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant ant task from maven-antrun-plugin? From the output it seems that you're trying to compile SwipeCardUtil with GWT compiler, that won't work, as the SmartCard API is not present on client side (in the browser). So there is no way for you to call it from JavaScript. Perhaps if that's your intention you'll have to package the SmartCard API dependent code in an applet to have it run in browser, and use live connect to call from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Zoran Regvart ! Although you didn't really provide an answer, you helped me get there by seeing my own silly mistake!

I had added the SwipeCardUtil class to the wrong util folder in the project! By moving it from the client side util folder to the server side util folder, I was able to compile the project and continue my work. Thank you for opening my eyes!